# "Floated away" block in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overflow

I decided to practice on the layout of sites and began to copy someone else and learn html markup and css properties. All was well until I did not open the site in Internet Explorer 8… http://hsu.su/ukt

[image: pic]

What I overlooked? what's wrong?
Sorry for the broken English

**original page**: 
 http://hsu.su/wq

Answer (score 2):

Surely enough, the website works in all browsers except for IE. In IE8 I put your HTML and CSS into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UhyUf/) and it worked fine in IE (see link for example).

This would suggest your HTML isn't quite formatted correctly. The most obvious thing was that you didn't declare a doctype. If you don't know what that is, more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_doctype.asp). So I took your code and put this pretty standard doctype in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

And surely enough, IE8 started displaying it correctly.

Comment: @user1103744, I'm glad I did! If this the right answer, please click the tick under the voting number so that other people will see it if they come across this question.

Answer (score 1):

The element containing the image and the text has to clear the float, or have overflow set to hidden:

```
clear: left;
overflow: hidden;
```

Overflow hidden forces the container to extend down to the height of image, even if it is floated.